# How to access both images and extracts on a Wikipedia page via the API?

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I am trying to access images and extracts on a Wikipedia page via the API.

According to [the documentation](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aProperties#images_.2F_im), the way to do this is to add `prop=images` to the request URL.

```
api.php?action=query&titles=Albert%20Einstein&prop=images
```

But if I combine extracts and images

```
api.php?action=query&titles=Albert%20Einstein&prop=images&extracts
```

I get the following response

```
parsed_response={"warnings"=>{"main"=>{"*"=>"Unrecognized parameter: 'images'"}}
```

Each of these works individually. Combining other props (e.g., `extracts&exintro&explaintext&redirects`) also works.

Why can't I get extracts and images via a single API request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It [should be](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php) | in the place of &:

[`api.php?action=query&titles=Albert%20Einstein&prop=images|extracts`](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Albert%20Einstein&prop=images|extracts)

`extracts&exintro&explaintext` happens to work, because `exintro` and `explaintext` are *not* properties, but extra parameters that can be added when using `prop=extracts`. To combine them all, use

[`api.php?action=query&titles=Albert%20Einstein&prop=images|extracts&exintro&explaintext`](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Albert%20Einstein&prop=images|extracts&exintro&explaintext)

Comment: thanks leo! I must have overlooked this in the docs. Can you point me towards where this is described?

Comment: Right on the top :-)

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php (`prop [...] Values (separate with '|')`)